# display category in a grouped product detail view magento

Tags: html, magento, php

I'm currently using magento community. I have several grouped products. For example, I have cologne Polo Green, which is a grouped product. The products in that group are the 2.5oz; 3.4oz, 6.7oz, etc.

At the same time, I would like to add the category "After Shave" which will display the after shave products.

How can I add the category within the grouped product?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you have to assign same category to all child product which you assign in group product.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below custom module

**1) config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_YourModulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </NameSpace_YourModulename>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <NameSpace_YourModulename_Product_Update>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>NameSpace_YourModulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customApplyCategoryToGrouped</method>
                    </NameSpace_YourModulename_Product_Update>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
   <global>
    <models>
        <NameSpace_YourModulename>
            <class>NameSpace_YourModulename_Model</class>
        </NameSpace_YourModulename>
    </models>
   </global>
</config>
```

2) Observer.php file inside model

```
<?php
  class NameSpace_YourModulename_Model_Observer
{   
    public function customApplyCategoryToGrouped(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $currentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($observer->getProduct()->getId());
        $categoryIds = $currentProduct->getCategoryIds();
        if($currentProduct->getTypeId() == 'grouped')
        $simpleProducts = $currentProduct->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($currentProduct);
        if(count($simpleProducts) > 0)        
         foreach ($simpleProducts as $item) {
             $_simplePro = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
             $_simplePro->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
             $_simplePro->save();
             unset($_simplePro);
           }
    }
}
```

3 ) etc/modules/NameSpace_YourModulename.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <NameSpace_YourModulename>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </NameSpace_YourModulename>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

So far I have the following, please correct if I am wrong

The first section goes to config at...

app>code>local>Myfile>Pt003(myfile)>etc = config.xml

The second goes to...

app>code>mage>persistent>model = Observer.php

The third is a given...

Thanks for the reply.